# SAML2 usage with axis2 web service

Tags: apache-axis, saml

Is there any way that i can use SAML to authenticate(SSO) to an Idp using an axis2 web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAML WebBrowser SSO Profile is used to convey an authentication assertion FROM an IdP (identity provider) TO a SP (service provider), which may result in authentication occurring at the SP.  SAML SSO isn't used to perform authentication to an IdP.  An SP can send an authentication request (AuthnRequest) to an IdP, but that's simply a request, not the authentication itself.  The SAML SSO profile allows for AuthnRequest over HTTP (Redirect/POST/Artifact) and Response (the authentication assertion from the IdP) over HTTP (POST/Artifact).  If IdP supports/uses HTTP Artifact, then the authentication assertions would be obtained by calling a web service at the IdP, rather than being conveyed directly in the response XML.

Perhaps you should look at the Enhanced Client or Proxy (ECP) profile, which uses Reverse SOAP (PAOS).  This certainly would be possible with Axis2, although to be clear, the web service itself would live at the IdP.

Which end are you implementing, IdP or SP?

Comment: I'm implementing the SP part and I use WSO2 Identity Server as the IdP. They don't support ECP right now. Do you have any suggestions to implement this?

Comment: I'm still confused as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  Is it web browser SSO or web service authentication (WS-Security)?  It's unclear where web services would come into play in the former, since it's not really relevant to web browser SSO unless you're using artifacts or attribute queries or something.  You can do just about anything with OpenSAML, but that may be overkill for you.  (I say that having used OpenSAML a lot.)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I want a system like this: User authenticates to the system (this authentication should be SSO) but there are different applications in the system, so user must authenticate only once. Once he authenticate one application, he/she should not need to give the credientials to the other application. This part is about the SSO. Then, after authentication, user should have a session and whenever he wants to access a resource on the system, i want to check this session and check if it is authorized and have permission to access this resource.

Comment: The last one is the web service authentication part. I hope this makes the picture a bit more cleaner in your mind. Am i on the wrong track?

Comment: Not sure what kind of 'resource' is meant.  If it's a page accessed through a URL, then you want Web Browser SSO, and either accessing the page needs to trigger an AuthnRequest back to the IdP, which responds with SAMLResponse XML, resulting in user being authenticated at SP and allowed to view the page, or IdP can control link to page, passing unsolicited SAMLResponse XML to SP to authenticate and view the page.  If accessing through a web service, you can use WS-Security to include SAML XML in the header and use that to determine whether caller is authorized to access the web service.

Comment: Keep in mind that SAML itself does not give you access to a session on the system, it just conveys authentication assertion information.  So when you say 'I want to check this session and check if it is authorized' that's outside of what SAML provides for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the saml library opensaml http://www.opensaml.org/ to generate your authnRequest and process the response sent by the idp.